# selectList razor tag helpers asp.netCore

Tags: entity-framework, linq, razor, asp.net-core

I want to make a drop down list of "Trailers" and "Customers" available in my "Order" form. I am able to use the Html tag helper to pass Trailer data from database to the view in the "Order" form but i am not able to do the same for Customers using the razor select tag helper. Why isn't the razor select tag helper not passing values from the database to the view? Below are snippets of my code. I am confused as to why it's not working

---

Trailer Class

```
public class Trailer
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string TrailerNumber { get; set; }
    public string TrailerStatus { get; set; }

    public int TrailerID { get; set; }

    public virtual Order OrderforTrailer { get; set; }

    public Trailer()
    {
        TrailerStatus = "Available";
    }
}
```

---

Customer class

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public IList<Order> CustomerOrders { get; set; }
}
```

---

Order Class

```
public class Order
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public int TrailerForLoadID { get; set; }
    public virtual Trailer TrailerForLoad { get; set; }

    public int CustomerOrdersID { get; set;}
    public virtual Customer CustomerOrders { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
        OrderStatus = "Available";
    }

}
```

---

AddOrderViewModel

```
public string OrderNumber { get; set; }

    public int TrailerID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> TrailersForLoad { get; set; }

    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> CustomersOrder { get; set; }

    public AddOrderViewModel()
    {
    }

    public AddOrderViewModel(IEnumerable<Trailer> trailersForLoad, IEnumerable<Customer> customersOrder)
    {

        TrailersForLoad = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var trailer in trailersForLoad)

        {
            TrailersForLoad.Add(new SelectListItem

            {
                Value = (trailer.TrailerID).ToString(),
                Text = trailer.TrailerNumber
            });
        };

        CustomersOrder = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (var customer in customersOrder)

        {
            CustomersOrder.Add(new SelectListItem

            {
                Value = (customer.CustomerID).ToString(),
                Text = customer.CustomerName
            });
        };

    }

}
```

Order controller

```
public IActionResult Add()
    {
        IList<Trailer> trailerForLoad = context.Trailers.Where
        (c => c.TrailerStatus == "Available").ToList();

        IList<Customer> customerOrder = context.Customers.ToList();

        AddOrderViewModel addOrderViewModel = 
        new AddOrderViewModel(trailerForLoad, customerOrder);

        return View(addOrderViewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add(AddOrderViewModel addOrderViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Order newOrder = new Order()
            {
                OrderNumber = addOrderViewModel.OrderNumber,

                TrailerForLoad = context.Trailers.
                Where(x => x.TrailerID == addOrderViewModel
                .TrailerID).Single(),

                CustomerOrders = context.Customers
                .Single(x => x.CustomerID==addOrderViewModel.CustomerID)
            };
            context.Orders.Add(newOrder);

        trailerSelected = context.Trailers.Where(x => 
        x.TrailerID == addOrderViewModel.TrailerID).Single();

        trailerSelected.TrailerStatus = "Unavailable";   
        context.SaveChanges();
        return Redirect("/Order");
        }
        return View(addOrderViewModel);
    }
```

---

The form in the view should display a list of customers

```
<form asp-controller="Order" asp-action="Add" method="post">

<fieldset>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="OrderNumber">Order number </label>
        <input class="form-control" asp-for="OrderNumber" />
        <span asp-validation-for="OrderNumber"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="TrailersForLoad">Trailer</label>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TrailerID, Model.TrailersForLoad)
        <span asp-validation-for="TrailersForLoad"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CustomerID">Customers Name</label>
        <select asp-for="CustomerID" 
        asp-items="Model.CustomersOrder"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="CustomerID"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submitButton" />
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the SELECT tag helper incorrectly. In your current code, you are using a self closing tag approach! Instead you should use an explicit `</SELECT>` closing tag

This should work

```
<select asp-for="CustomerID" asp-items="Model.CustomersOrder"></select>
```